# sorting array of struct by id

Tags: c++

I take an array of record as case study in my Graduation Project.  In the code I've written, I made an array of the structure and entered the id of the structs in an array 
of int to make the sorting easier but when it runs it gets stuck.

```
#include<iostream.h>
struct book{
    char Bname[8], Bsubject[8];
    int copyies, Bid, Bfound;
} a[100];

void Ider(book a[],int r[],int index){
    for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
        r[i]=a[i].Bid;
}

void swap(int &a,int &b){
    int c=a;
    a=b;
    b=c;
}

void Bublesort(int a[],int n){
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    for(int i=1;i<n-1;i++)
        if(a[i]>a[i+1])
            swap(a[i+1],a[i]);                
}

int bsearch(int b[],int key,int first,int last){
    int  midel=(first+last)/2;
    for(int i=0;i<last;i++){
        if(b[midel]==key)
            return midel;
        else 
            if(b[midel]>key)
                return bsearch(b,key,first,midel-1);
            else 
                if(b[midel]<key)
                    return bsearch(b,key,midel+1,last);
    }
}

int main(){

    int r,i, index=0,m[100];
    char ch;

    do{
        cout<<"Enter your"<<index+1<<" Book id"<<"    ";
        cout<<endl;
        cin>>a[index].Bid;
        cout<<"Enter your"<<index+1<<" Book name"<<"    ";
        cout<<endl;

         cin>>a[index].Bname;

         cout<<"Enter your"<<index+1<<" Book subject"<<"    ";
         cout<<endl;

         cin>>a[index].Bsubject;
         index++;
         a[index].Bfound++;
         a[index].copyies++;
         if(index==99)
             break;

    quite : cout<<"Do you want to continue";
         cin>>ch;

    } while(ch=='y');

    Ider(a,m,index);
    Bublesort(m,index);

    char p;

    do{
        cout<<"Do you want to search?"<<endl;
        cin>>p;
        cout<<"enter your id";
        cin>>i; 
        r=bsearch(m,i,0,index);
        cout<<a[r].Bfound<<"          ";

    } while(ch=='y');

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When it reaches `bublesort()` it hangs and didn't give any output, but why?

Comment: I don't see any `oop` here, just a struct and functions. Is this supposed to be object oriented?

Comment: @AbdallaAdam: Not really. That code would compile (except the inclusion of <iostream.h> [BTW, that header is deprecated, it should be <iostream>]) in C, which is not an OO language... the implication being that there is no object orientation in the code. Whether you want or need it is a completely different issue, but the question should not be tagged OOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other problems: a bubblesort goes over the array again and again until it's completely sorted. Yours only goes over the array once.

[C example](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/sorting1.html)

[Bubble sort (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)